# access numeric objects from json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am retrieving some JSON array from PHP in javascript using ajax. First, I parse JSON array and the access each element using a loop. Now I am stuck on a problem there are some numeric objects in JSON array and I can't access them. My JSON array looks like this:

```js
[
    {
        "Name": "Umar Ghaffar",
        "UniqueID": "b57a956420b885ebb",
        "loggined": "no",
        "Type": "Security",
        "0": "0",    // how can i get the value of this object
        "1": "1"
    },

    {
        "Name": "Usama Ghaffar",
        "UniqueID": "af4dc4ac58ee0eb54",
        "loggined": "",
        "Type": "Security",
        "0": "0",
        "1": "0"
    }
]
```

This is how I am accessing array

```js
var newText1 = document.createTextNode(data[i].Name);
var newText2 = document.createTextNode(data[i].UniqueID);
var newText3 = document.createTextNode(data[i].loggined);
var newText4 = document.createTextNode(data[i].Type);
var newText5 = document.createTextNode(data[i].0); //here it gives an error
```

Comment: `data[i]["0"]` should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using bracket notation:

```
 var newText5  = document.createTextNode(data[i]["0"])
```